# Mentioning Guest using Slack Bot?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I have numerous guests in my channel.

I'd like my bot to mention these guests in a @ mention, but bots don't seem to see channel guests. It find other full users fine, just none of the guests.

Is this an intentional limitation of Slack or does the bot require more permissions?

I'm using the `slackclient` module (Python) and making the following call:

```
    sc.client.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel="#channel",
        link_names=1,
        text="@aaron.layfield <-- Working @guest.name <-- Not working This is a message."
    )
```

Comment: Are you having trouble finding the ID of the guest user, or is the message not appearing as tagging them when you use the `<@U1234567>` format?

Comment: @Dandy please be more specific what you are doing. Are you looking for the user in users.list? Best would be if you would add the relevant part of your code to your question. Ty

Comment: @ColmDoyle I've tried using unparsed user ID and parsed user ID. This works perfect if I use my tag (@aaron.layfield) but if I use a guests (@guest.name) the bot does not resolve the name.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Updated to provide a code example. Sorry for the lack of specifics.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link to users from inside of your message, the best [format](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users) to use is `<@USERID>` instead of `@username`. This is because Slack has [moved away](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames) from using usernames, and towards a more flexible concept of display names, which aren't guaranteed to be unique or immutable.

So in this case, you would do something like

```
curl --request 'POST' 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xoxb-21321321-1231321321321-dsfasdgdsfaghsdfhsdfh&channel=C9UFK5F5S&text=Hey <@UFBKH3B63>'
```

Which would render as

> Hey @Colm Doyle

Answer (score 0):

As already explained by Colm's answer the @username syntax is depreciated and you should use the ID syntax instead for mentions.

To get the IDs for your guest users call [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) to get a list of all users in your workspace. Then iterate through that list to match guest name with ID.